# Copy and paste on iPad selects whole sentences after loading libertine

Tags: xetex, fontspec, libertine

I have the following minimal document:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}


\usepackage{fontspec}

%\setmainfont{Code2000} % works on texlive 2014


\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O} % does not work     



\begin{document}

This is some arbitrary text. I want it to be selectable word by word.
This is some arbitrary text. I want it to be selectable word by word.
This is some arbitrary text. I want it to be selectable word by word.
This is some arbitrary text. I want it to be selectable word by word.
This is some arbitrary text. I want it to be selectable word by word.
This is some arbitrary text. I want it to be selectable word by word.
This is some arbitrary text. I want it to be selectable word by word.
This is some arbitrary text. I want it to be selectable word by word.




\end{document}
```

When I comment the `setmainfont` command and compile the document with xelatex, I get something that behaves well on an iPad as far as copy and paste is concerned: When I tap a word, this word is selected. With `setmainfont` commented in, I get a document where tapping selects a whole sentence or phrase. Is there anything I can do about this? I am using texlive 2014 with all packages updated.

Here are two screenshots. The first picture shows the expected behaviour: Tap on "selectable" and "selectable" is selected.

[image]

The document with libertine has a complete sentence selected or rather the area from the beginning of the line to the next dot or also "-":

[image]

Maybe it has something to do with the treatment of space. I could imagine that the spaces are not recognized by the selection software on the iPad and it just thinks that the complete sentence is a spaceless object.

These are the created PDFs:

[Libertine](http://hpsg.fu-berlin.de/~stefan/transfer/test-ebook-libertine.pdf)

[OpenSans](http://hpsg.fu-berlin.de/~stefan/transfer/test-ebook-opensans.pdf)

The log file says:

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99991 (TeX Live 2014) (preloaded format=xelatex 2015.2.16)  16 FEB 2015 16:37
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**test-ebook
(./test-ebook.tex
LaTeX2e <2014/05/01>
Babel <3.9l> and hyphenation patterns for 79 languages loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/book.cls
Document Class: book 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/bk10.clo
File: bk10.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count80
\c@chapter=\count81
\c@section=\count82
\c@subsection=\count83
\c@subsubsection=\count84
\c@paragraph=\count85
\c@subparagraph=\count86
\c@figure=\count87
\c@table=\count88
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.sty
Package: fontspec 2014/06/21 v2.4a Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX

(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
Package: expl3 2015/02/13 v5524 L3 programming layer (loader) 

(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3-code.tex
Package: expl3 2015/02/13 v5524 L3 programming layer (code) 
L3 Module: l3bootstrap 2015/01/27 v5500 L3 Bootstrap code

(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etex-pkg/etex.sty
Package: etex 1998/03/26 v2.0 eTeX basic definition package (PEB)
\et@xins=\count89
)
L3 Module: l3names 2014/08/22 v5343 L3 Namespace for primitives
L3 Module: l3basics 2015/01/27 v5500 L3 Basic definitions
L3 Module: l3expan 2014/11/27 v5472 L3 Argument expansion
L3 Module: l3tl 2015/01/27 v5500 L3 Token lists
L3 Module: l3str 2014/08/24 v5368 L3 Strings
L3 Module: l3seq 2014/08/23 v5354 L3 Sequences and stacks
L3 Module: l3int 2014/09/14 v5421 L3 Integers
\c_max_int=\count90
\l_tmpa_int=\count91
\l_tmpb_int=\count92
\g_tmpa_int=\count93
\g_tmpb_int=\count94
L3 Module: l3quark 2014/08/23 v5354 L3 Quarks
L3 Module: l3prg 2014/08/23 v5354 L3 Control structures
\g__prg_map_int=\count95
L3 Module: l3clist 2014/08/23 v5354 L3 Comma separated lists
L3 Module: l3token 2014/09/15 v5422 L3 Experimental token manipulation
L3 Module: l3prop 2014/08/23 v5354 L3 Property lists
L3 Module: l3msg 2014/08/24 v5358 L3 Messages
L3 Module: l3file 2014/08/24 v5369 L3 File and I/O operations
\l_iow_line_count_int=\count96
\l__iow_target_count_int=\count97
\l__iow_current_line_int=\count98
\l__iow_current_word_int=\count99
\l__iow_current_indentation_int=\count100
L3 Module: l3skip 2014/08/23 v5354 L3 Dimensions and skips
\c_zero_dim=\dimen103
\c_max_dim=\dimen104
\l_tmpa_dim=\dimen105
\l_tmpb_dim=\dimen106
\g_tmpa_dim=\dimen107
\g_tmpb_dim=\dimen108
\c_zero_skip=\skip43
\c_max_skip=\skip44
\l_tmpa_skip=\skip45
\l_tmpb_skip=\skip46
\g_tmpa_skip=\skip47
\g_tmpb_skip=\skip48
\c_zero_muskip=\muskip10
\c_max_muskip=\muskip11
\l_tmpa_muskip=\muskip12
\l_tmpb_muskip=\muskip13
\g_tmpa_muskip=\muskip14
\g_tmpb_muskip=\muskip15
L3 Module: l3keys 2015/01/27 v5500 L3 Key-value interfaces
\g__keyval_level_int=\count101
\l_keys_choice_int=\count102
L3 Module: l3fp 2014/08/22 v5336 L3 Floating points
\c__fp_leading_shift_int=\count103
\c__fp_middle_shift_int=\count104
\c__fp_trailing_shift_int=\count105
\c__fp_big_leading_shift_int=\count106
\c__fp_big_middle_shift_int=\count107
\c__fp_big_trailing_shift_int=\count108
\c__fp_Bigg_leading_shift_int=\count109
\c__fp_Bigg_middle_shift_int=\count110
\c__fp_Bigg_trailing_shift_int=\count111
L3 Module: l3box 2014/08/23 v5354 L3 Experimental boxes
\c_empty_box=\box26
\l_tmpa_box=\box27
\l_tmpb_box=\box28
\g_tmpa_box=\box29
\g_tmpb_box=\box30
L3 Module: l3coffins 2014/08/23 v5354 L3 Coffin code layer
\l__coffin_internal_box=\box31
\l__coffin_internal_dim=\dimen109
\l__coffin_offset_x_dim=\dimen110
\l__coffin_offset_y_dim=\dimen111
\l__coffin_x_dim=\dimen112
\l__coffin_y_dim=\dimen113
\l__coffin_x_prime_dim=\dimen114
\l__coffin_y_prime_dim=\dimen115
\c_empty_coffin=\box32
\l__coffin_aligned_coffin=\box33
\l__coffin_aligned_internal_coffin=\box34
\l_tmpa_coffin=\box35
\l_tmpb_coffin=\box36
\l__coffin_display_coffin=\box37
\l__coffin_display_coord_coffin=\box38
\l__coffin_display_pole_coffin=\box39
\l__coffin_display_offset_dim=\dimen116
\l__coffin_display_x_dim=\dimen117
\l__coffin_display_y_dim=\dimen118
L3 Module: l3color 2014/08/23 v5354 L3 Experimental color support
L3 Module: l3candidates 2015/02/12 v5523 L3 Experimental additions to l3kernel
\l__box_top_dim=\dimen119
\l__box_bottom_dim=\dimen120
\l__box_left_dim=\dimen121
\l__box_right_dim=\dimen122
\l__box_top_new_dim=\dimen123
\l__box_bottom_new_dim=\dimen124
\l__box_left_new_dim=\dimen125
\l__box_right_new_dim=\dimen126
\l__box_internal_box=\box40
\l__coffin_bounding_shift_dim=\dimen127
\l__coffin_left_corner_dim=\dimen128
\l__coffin_right_corner_dim=\dimen129
\l__coffin_bottom_corner_dim=\dimen130
\l__coffin_top_corner_dim=\dimen131
\l__coffin_scaled_total_height_dim=\dimen132
\l__coffin_scaled_width_dim=\dimen133
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3unicode-data.def
File: l3unicode-data.def 2015/02/12 v5523 L3 Unicode data
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3xdvipdfmx.def
File: l3xdvidpfmx.def 2015/02/12 v5523 L3 Experimental driver: xdvipdfmx
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty
Package: xparse 2014/11/25 v5471 L3 Experimental document command parser
\l__xparse_current_arg_int=\count112
\l__xparse_m_args_int=\count113
\l__xparse_mandatory_args_int=\count114
\l__xparse_processor_int=\count115
\l__xparse_v_nesting_int=\count116
)
\l_fontspec_script_int=\count117
\l_fontspec_language_int=\count118
\l_fontspec_strnum_int=\count119
\l__fontspec_tmpa_dim=\dimen134
\l__fontspec_tmpb_dim=\dimen135
\l__fontspec_tmpc_dim=\dimen136
Variant \tl_gset:cV already defined; not changing it on line 71

(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec-patches.sty
Package: fontspec-patches 2014/06/21 v2.4a Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLa
TeX
LaTeX Info: Redefining \em on input line 38.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \emph on input line 46.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \- on input line 49.
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/redefine-command"
. 
. Redefining command \oldstylenums with sig. 'm' on line 144.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \liningnums with sig. 'm' on line 148.
.................................................
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec-xetex.sty
Package: fontspec-xetex 2014/06/21 v2.4a Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTe
X

(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
Package: fontenc 2005/09/27 v1.99g Standard LaTeX package

(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/euenc/eu1enc.def
File: eu1enc.def 2010/05/27 v0.1h Experimental Unicode font encodings
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for EU1+lmr on input line 100.


(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/euenc/eu1lmr.fd
File: eu1lmr.fd 2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xunicode/xunicode.sty
File: xunicode.sty 2011/09/09 v0.981 provides access to latin accents and many 
other characters in Unicode lower plane

(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tipa/t3enc.def
File: t3enc.def 2001/12/31 T3 encoding
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for EU1+lmss on input line 357
.

(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/euenc/eu1lmss.fd
File: eu1lmss.fd 2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
))
\tipaTiiicode=\count120
\tipasavetokens=\toks14
\tipachecktokens=\toks15

(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 2014/10/28 v1.0g Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks16
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2014/10/28 v1.0p Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty
Package: trig 1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/graphics.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2010/04/23 v1.9 graphics configuration of TeX Live
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: xetex.def on input line 91.

(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xetex-def/xetex.def
File: xetex.def 2014/07/25 v4.03 LaTeX color/graphics driver for XeTeX (RRM/JK)

))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen137
\Gin@req@width=\dimen138
))
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \fontspec with sig. 'O{}mO{}' on line 41.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \setmainfont with sig. 'O{}mO{}' on line 47.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \setsansfont with sig. 'O{}mO{}' on line 53.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \setmonofont with sig. 'O{}mO{}' on line 59.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \setmathrm with sig. 'O{}mO{}' on line 68.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \setboldmathrm with sig. 'O{}mO{}' on line 72.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \setmathsf with sig. 'O{}mO{}' on line 76.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \setmathtt with sig. 'O{}mO{}' on line 80.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \newfontfamily with sig. 'mO{}mO{}' on line 99.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \newfontface with sig. 'mO{}mO{}' on line 103.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \defaultfontfeatures with sig. 't+om' on line 112.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \addfontfeatures with sig. 'm' on line 170.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \newfontfeature with sig. 'mm' on line 181.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \newAATfeature with sig. 'mmmm' on line 189.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \newopentypefeature with sig. 'mmm' on line 197.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \aliasfontfeature with sig. 'mm' on line 226.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \aliasfontfeatureoption with sig. 'mmm' on line 228.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \newfontscript with sig. 'mm' on line 233.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \newfontlanguage with sig. 'mm' on line 259.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \DeclareFontsExtensions with sig. 'm' on line 279.
.................................................
Variant \prop_gput:cnV already defined; not changing it on line 662
Variant \prop_gput:cnx already defined; not changing it on line 663
\l__fontspec_tmp_int=\count121
LaTeX Info: Redefining \itshape on input line 2193.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \slshape on input line 2198.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \scshape on input line 2203.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \upshape on input line 2208.

(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.cfg)))
\g__file_internal_ior=\read1
\g__fontspec_family_LinuxLibertineO_int=\count122
.................................................
. fontspec info: "defining-font"
. 
. Font family 'LinuxLibertineO(0)' created for font 'Linux Libertine O' with
. options [Ligatures=TeX].
. 
. This font family consists of the following shapes:
. 
. * 'normal' with NFSS spec.:
. <->"Linux Libertine O/OT:script=latn;language=DFLT;mapping=tex-text;"
. 
. * 'small caps' with NFSS spec.:
. <->"Linux Libertine O/OT:script=latn;language=DFLT;mapping=tex-text;+smcp;"
. and font adjustment code:
. 
. 
. * 'bold' with NFSS spec.:
. <->"Linux Libertine O/B/OT:script=latn;language=DFLT;mapping=tex-text;"
. 
. * 'bold small caps' with NFSS spec.:
. <->"Linux Libertine
. O/B/OT:script=latn;language=DFLT;mapping=tex-text;+smcp;"
. and font adjustment code:
. 
. 
. * 'italic' with NFSS spec.:
. <->"Linux Libertine O/I/OT:script=latn;language=DFLT;mapping=tex-text;"
. 
. * 'small caps' with NFSS spec.:
. <->"Linux Libertine
. O/I/OT:script=latn;language=DFLT;mapping=tex-text;+smcp;"
. and font adjustment code:
. 
. 
. * 'bold italic' with NFSS spec.:
. <->"Linux Libertine O/BI/OT:script=latn;language=DFLT;mapping=tex-text;"
. 
. * 'bold small caps' with NFSS spec.:
. <->"Linux Libertine
. O/BI/OT:script=latn;language=DFLT;mapping=tex-text;+smcp;"
. and font adjustment code:
. 
.................................................

(./test-ebook.aux)
\openout1 = `test-ebook.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 26.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 26.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 26.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 26.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 26.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 26.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 26.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 26.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 26.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 26.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 26.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 26.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for EU1/lmr/m/n on input line 26.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 26.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T3/cmr/m/n on input line 26.
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for T3+cmr on input line 26.
 (/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tipa/t3cmr.fd
File: t3cmr.fd 2001/12/31 TIPA font definitions
)
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 26.
.................................................
. fontspec info: "setup-math"
. 
. Adjusting the maths setup (use [no-math] to avoid this).
.................................................
\symlegacymaths=\mathgroup4
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `legacymaths' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/n --> OT1/cmr/bx/n on input line 26.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \acute on input line 26.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \grave on input line 26.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \ddot on input line 26.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \tilde on input line 26.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \bar on input line 26.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \breve on input line 26.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \check on input line 26.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \hat on input line 26.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \dot on input line 26.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \mathring on input line 26.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \colon on input line 26.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Gamma on input line 26.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Delta on input line 26.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Theta on input line 26.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Lambda on input line 26.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Xi on input line 26.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Pi on input line 26.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Sigma on input line 26.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Upsilon on input line 26.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Phi on input line 26.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Psi on input line 26.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Omega on input line 26.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \mathdollar on input line 26.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring symbol font `operators' on input line 26.
LaTeX Font Info:    Encoding `OT1' has changed to `EU1' for symbol font
(Font)              `operators' in the math version `normal' on input line 26.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/n --> EU1/LinuxLibertineO(0)/m/n on input lin
e 26.
LaTeX Font Info:    Encoding `OT1' has changed to `EU1' for symbol font
(Font)              `operators' in the math version `bold' on input line 26.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> EU1/LinuxLibertineO(0)/m/n on input li
ne 26.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `normal'
(Font)                  EU1/LinuxLibertineO(0)/m/n --> EU1/LinuxLibertineO(0)/m
/n on input line 26.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/it --> EU1/LinuxLibertineO(0)/m/it on input l
ine 26.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> EU1/LinuxLibertineO(0)/bx/n on input l
ine 26.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/m/n --> EU1/lmss/m/n on input line 26.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> EU1/lmtt/m/n on input line 26.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `bold'
(Font)                  EU1/LinuxLibertineO(0)/m/n --> EU1/LinuxLibertineO(0)/b
x/n on input line 26.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/it --> EU1/LinuxLibertineO(0)/bx/it on input
 line 26.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/bx/n --> EU1/lmss/bx/n on input line 26.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> EU1/lmtt/bx/n on input line 26.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `EU1/LinuxLibertineO(0)/m/sl' in size <10> not a
vailable
(Font)              Font shape `EU1/LinuxLibertineO(0)/m/it' tried instead on i
nput line 40.
[1

] (./test-ebook.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 13194 strings out of 493724
 277883 string characters out of 6145899
 303352 words of memory out of 5000000
 16502 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 3907 words of font info for 26 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1328 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 46i,4n,59p,10357b,207s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s

Output written on test-ebook.pdf (1 page).
```

Comment: 1st: Did you try this on another OS/viewer? 2nd: Does this issue occur with Libertine only?

Comment: It happens with goodreader and with acroread. It does not happen with `OpenSans.ttf`.

Comment: I can't reproduce it with Chrome's in-house PDF viewer with *either* PDF, so I think it's an issue with the viewer implementation on your device (and thus off-topic).

Comment: Just checked it again. It is a problem with acroread on the iPad as well. So it is not just one PDF viewer. And the PDF that is the result of compiling the same document on a linux machine with a probably slightly different LaTeX installation does not have this problem. I would really like to know what is going on.

Comment: The pdf files you link to are not the product of your MWE, though. Do you have the problem either way?

Comment: Yes, it is the same problem. I just used \setmainfont{OpenSans} instead of code2000 in the example that works. Sorry.

Comment: I actually only looked at the `libertine` code. As a general rule, it's always best to post the output of your MWE and not of some other code that we can't see or inspect.

Comment: It is a known problem with the iPad and, to a lesser extent, with some other PDF viewers which include acroread. Both PDFs are fine with Okular embedded in Firefox (i.e. the kparts bit of Okular).

Comment: OK. Thanks. I did not know this. Is there any hope? The question is a year old and I wonder whether something is done about this or can be done. I would even pay or donate to a developer if that would help. (with several hundred real bounties)

Comment: I guess you would have to contact a developer of your favourite PDF viewer.  I don't know how your chances are with Adobe or Apple, but if you went for an open source viewer, developers might be open.

Comment: OK. It is a viewers problem. Then I am stuck since I am looking for a general solution for all (human) readers of these books. I thought it was font related since it works for some fonts.